# What are the disadvantages of refactoring multiple UseEffect into one?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have used multiple useEffect for different callback functions. Now, I get to [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001188/can-i-refactor-multiple-useeffect-to-single-useeffect) that I can refactor multiple useEffect into a single one, all the callback functions have different dependencies so is it a great idea to refactor all useEffect into a single one or is there any better approach to optimise the code and no need to use of multiple useEffect or use of multiple useEffect is common practice?

Comment: If for different components you need different side effects, then different useEffects may be used - so I would say it depends on use case.

Comment: Broadly speaking it's not a good idea to refactor this case where you have different dependencies.. You seem to be biassed in the sense that you think using less code or less functions is more optimized code. However this is only optimized in the "lines of code" sense of optimization. If you have repeating parts in each effect do extract them in their own function for sure but don't move all effects into one to reduce the number of lines with `useEffect` that's not actual optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depends on your dependencies (of your useEffect) and component , i think its better to split useEffect for each your concept , for example in one useEffect you have api call and in the other useEffect you have event listener and remove listeners and dependencies , because i think if you combine them , it may create unexpected re-render and side effect

Comment: And If the use case be like we have an empty dependency of array i.e. [] then is it good to combine?

Comment: @RitikBanger , I think its good to make your useEffect as simple as possible , if you see its doing another job in the useEffect , split them , i think its related to your convention too

Answer (score 0):

You want to have on `useEffect` for each different concern.
So as in the example you referred, you want to have on `useEffect` to add and remove listener. And if you have another concern, add different `useEffect`.
Good way to check is if you can remove on `useEffect` from your component and the rest wouldn't be affected